# Selectively submit fields using jQuery without AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form which can dynamically expand and can end up with 400+ input capable fields on it.
I would like to selectively decide which fields are posted when the form is submitted (Not by AJAX) so that only fields where the values have changed are submitted.

I know that only input fields that have a name attribute are actually posted so my idea is to take each element Id (that has changed) and add a name attribute using JQuery like so:-

> $('#field1').attr('name', 'field1');

This would be just before the submit and so (in theory) only the fields that have changed are submitted.

I have trawled through Google looking for examples that do this but suprisingly can't find any examples anywhere.  The closest I have seen is someone mentioning to disable fields before Submit.

So my questions are:-
Will this idea work?
If so, are there any negative reasons for using this approach?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you add the `name` attributes via JS, no one could use your site with JS disabled.

Comment: @feeela people don't still do that though do they ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky I'm not "the people", but yes – not having JS enabled is a fully valid user option. A website always should work without relying on JS or any browser plugins. If you don't see why that's  beneficial, you should check out the [WCAG](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag).

Comment: @NimChimpsky Which is your personal option, as I have mine. But the official W3C politics is to build and deliver accessible websites. That also includes a technical accessibility. See the WCAG link above…

Comment: This project is for a customer who will have javascript enabled - I would get all sorts of issues if javascript was turned off :)

Comment: @mazzaC Having a website that works with or without javascript is part of specifications/requirements (i.e. you make a B2B online shop where all users must be logged in to access the website, & must have javascript enabled). Hence the "it should work without javascript" argument does not hold, unless being a clear requirement.

Comment: Note: I agree that we should try to make websites screen-reader-friendly, by trying I mean what most do: develop screen reader friendly without testing. This could be done much better by getting it tested by blind people (instead of hoping our code works 'ok' on screen-readers). How many unexpected behaviors are we not aware of? this might be an interesting question to ask a group of blind people using screen-readers. For instance a small syntax error seem to completely disable the screen-reader interpretation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21586478/759452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input').change(function(){
  var newName = $(this).attr("id"); //could use any attribute, maybe data-name
  $(this).attr("name", newName);
})
```

When any input field has changed, the id gets added to field as its name.

For the general desgin issue, I would probably submit the whole form, and only update changed fields server side  - it would actually be handled by hibernate in my case.

Comment: This assumes that each input field has an ID assigned. Also you can't send arrays that way.

Comment: @feeela yeah it does assume that, what arrays and where am I sending them ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think this is really answering my question. I know how to change the name attibute of my fields and when to do it. I just don't know if this is the right way to do it - due to lack of other examples of this on the web.

Comment: Feeela - I am curious - why can't you send arrays this way?

Comment: I am curious where anyone sees an array in my answer

Comment: @NimChimpsky No one sees arrays in your answer and no one has said so. I don't know where you get this from ;-) [at]mazzaC: In HTML 4 the ID attribute must only consist of ASCII letters and digits plus '_', '-' and '.'. (This rule will lose in HTML5, but most browser still have impemented the old rules.) But for creating arrays from a form you need the square brackets `[` and `]`. For example `<input name="items[1]" /><input name="items[2]" />` will result in an PHP array with two items: `$_POST['items'][1]; $_POST['items'][2];`

Comment: Thanks for the comments NimChimpsky.  I would rather avoid server side validation as this would require expensive database access (unless I passed back some hidden changed flag which is another option I suppose.  Feeela's first comment mentioned arrays.  I'm a little bit confused about this as I would like the name attribute to be an Array so that my PHP can handle it easier.  Would this be a problem?

Comment: @mazzaC You really should implement a server side validation. Anything that lives ion the client is just optional and may get manipulated before sending.

Comment: Agreed, there will be server side validation.  What I meant that I would require database access to know if a value has changed since submission.  I am hoping to avoid this by doing this selective post.  I have other options such as storing all the data in a session array and checking against this on return but I think this may have memory implications later on due to the shear amount of data being handled.

Comment: Ok, I am accepting this as my answer.  From the comments I have established that this will work providing Javascript is turned on - which it will be in this case.  There are also issues with data manipulation but again this isn't an issue for me as this is non-sensitive data and it is on a protected website.  Thanks for the responses.